# How to display the order of number of elements in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to handle the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
ID,age,Year
100,75,2020
100,76,2021
200,64,2020
200,65,2021
200,66,2022
300,69,2020
300,70,2021
300,71,2022
300,72,2023
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'age'])
df
         Year
ID  age 
100 75  2020
    76  2021
200 64  2020
    65  2021
    66  2022
300 69  2020
    70  2021
    71  2022
    72  2023
```

The **ID** in this data frame represents the **same person**, and **Year** means the year of the visit.

This will be multi-indexed based on **ID** and **age**. At this point, is it possible to display from the **ID** with more **age** elements?

The ideal display is shown below.

```
        Year
ID  age 
300 69  2020
    70  2021
    71  2022
    72  2023
200 64  2020
    65  2021
    66  2022
100 75  2020
    76  2021
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless it's a requirement you immediately `set_index` after your `.read_csv`, then the following should be reasonably okay...

Get a count of how many times an ID occurs - we can use `.value_counts` for this which handily automatically sorts by descending order...

```
id_freq = df['ID'].value_counts()
```

*Then* index your DF and `.reindex` using the index of `id_freq`, eg:

```
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'age']).reindex(id_freq.index, level=0)
```

This'll give you:

```
         Year
ID  age      
300 69   2020
    70   2021
    71   2022
    72   2023
200 64   2020
    65   2021
    66   2022
100 75   2020
    76   2021
```

Might also have a side effect of being useful as you could also run `id_freq.value_counts()` to get a distribution of how many times each patient in general appears.

---

If you do have to index from the start, then you might as well provide it to `.read_csv`, such as:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data), index_col=['ID', 'age'])
```

Then similar to above, reindex but on the level values of the first level of the index, eg:

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.get_level_values(0).value_counts().index, level=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first compute the length of each `ID` group using `groupby` and `size`, and then sort the `ID` values based on the length:

```py
s = df.groupby('ID').size()
df.sort_values('ID', key=lambda i:s[i], ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
         Year
ID  age
300 69   2020
    70   2021
    71   2022
    72   2023
200 64   2020
    65   2021
    66   2022
100 75   2020
    76   2021
```

Comment: I'm not sure... but... `df.reindex(df.index.get_level_values(0).value_counts().index, level=0)` might be another option

Comment: @JonClements yeah, that works well - nice use of the fact that `value_counts` sorts descending. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Still playing with a couple of ideas...

Comment: Faster by about 40% than my solution. Please post something so I can delete mine and make yours stand out from the others...

Comment: Meh... had a pop at it... don't delete your answer though... I think it's useful

Comment: @JonClements ok... but what's annoying is that all the wrong answers (sorting based on the ID value rather than its length) are all the same score too...

Comment: To be fair... given the input/output example - it does look like a "just sort the index?"... so when I saw answers poring in, I thought no point adding to those... and then saw your answer and thought... ahhhhh.... I'm not the only one that read it a diferent... woo hoo... so thanks to yourself as well...

Comment: @JonClements you're right, the choice of input data was unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort based on two columns and set which column ascending and which not ascending like below:

```
>>> print(df.sort_values(['ID', 'age'], ascending=[False, True]))

         Year
ID  age      
300 69   2020
    70   2021
    71   2022
    72   2023
200 64   2020
    65   2021
    66   2022
100 75   2020
    76   2021
```

Comment: OP asks: "is it possible to display from the ID with more age elements?" That is not what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort these values like this:

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'age'],
          ascending = [False, True])
```

Comment: OP asks: "is it possible to display from the ID with more age elements?" That is not what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

pandas `sort_index()` is useful for sorting dataframe by index values.

```
df.sort_index(ascending=[False, True])
```

Comment: OP asks: "is it possible to display from the ID with more age elements?" That is not what your code does.